# Folder polling in a cluster

Tags: spring, redis, spring-integration

I have a spring integration app deployed on two nodes in a cluster. they poll for incoming files on single directory using inbound file adapter .
I have below configuration.

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundAdapter" channel="in" directory="file:${in.folder}" queue-size="100000"
      filter="incoimngCompositeFilter">
    <int:poller id="fileInboudPoller" fixed-rate="${in.interval}" receive-timeout="${file.in.timeout}" time-unit="SECONDS"
      max-messages-per-poll="${file.in.max.messages}" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="incoimngCompositeFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
  <constructor-arg>
    <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
            <constructor-arg name="store" ref="redisMetaDataStore" />
            <constructor-arg name="prefix" value="test"/>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.RegexPatternFileListFilter">
            <constructor-arg value="(?i)^(?!.*writing).*$" />
        </bean>
    </list>
  </constructor-arg></bean><bean name="redisMetaDataStore" class="org.springframework.integration.redis.metadata.RedisMetadataStore">
  <constructor-arg name="connectionFactory" ref="redisConnectionFactory" </bean><bean id="redisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
  <property name="port" value="6379" />
</bean>
```

I am getting intermittent results. Sometime it process with out any issue but sometime one instance is trying to process the files that are already processed by other instance.
Can someone point me to a sample using FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter and RedisMetadataStore?

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the files? Are they atomically moved once written?

If you are writing them in-place, it is possible both adapters will see the file because the timestamp changed.

The filter will only pass the file if it's not in the store, or the `lastModified` date has changed.